# How do you minimize an application in C++ Builder XE7 with FMX?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, firemonkey

How do you minimize an application in C++ Builder XE7 with FMX?

In the VCL, you could call Application->Minimize (). In FMX, that doesn't seem to be available.

Answer (score 1):

how about minimizing main form?

```
Application.MainForm.WindowState := TWindowState.wsMinimized;
```

Comment: Before writing such stuff, please take a look to VCL.Forms file, procedure TApplication.Minimize. Basically, if form is on main task bar (task bar on iOS?) then calling FMainForm.WindowState := wsMinimized

you could do this directly by sample which I provide.

if FMainFormOnTaskBar then
    begin
      if FMainForm <> nil then
        FMainForm.WindowState := wsMinimized

Comment: @ApulGupta -- without seeing Anthony app i could suggest him to minimize main form. This action should hide all other application forms. Of course, may his application not tipical and for some reason hiding main form not hiding other forms.... but once again -- try Delphi before writing useless comments. have a nice day!

Comment: @ApulGupta. Are you Delphi developer?

Please check TApplication.Minimize code:

procedure TApplication.Minimize;
begin
  if not IsIconic(Handle) then
  begin
    NormalizeTopMosts;
    if not MainFormOnTaskBar then
      SetActiveWindow(Handle); // WM_ACTIVATEAPP can set AppIconic to False
    FAppIconic := True;        // Set AppIconic here just to be safe
    DoShowOwnedPopups(False);
    if FMainFormOnTaskBar then
    begin
      if FMainForm <> nil then
        FMainForm.WindowState := wsMinimized
      else
        FInitialMainFormState := wsMinimized;
    end
    else

Comment: I've tried setting the program's main form to wsMinimized. This works, but the program doesn't pop back up on my test system (Windows 7) on the first click on the program's icon in the taskbar. Rather, it takes two clicks, for some reason.

Comment: @AnthonyBurg, very interesting behavior, I don't have such